# Can't get my inputs to show rows and columns in javascript

Tags: javascript, rows

So I'm supposed to create a nested 'for loop' that iterates through x (columns) and y(rows) up to the user-entered size to form a pattern of some sort and generate an interesting pattern (using the x and y values to make decisions) that places the three user-provided characters in a 2-dimensional grid."

I'm mostly having a problem with the rows and columns. I keep getting one columns and too many rows. After it posts the three characters entered it starts to print undefined and NaN. I'm not sure why but here is the part of the code with other commented out code I was trying to get to work as well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Lab </title>
    </head>
    <style>
    </style>
    <body>
        <h1> </h1>
        <p id= 'myParagraph'> My Paragraph! </p>
    </body>
    <script>

    //prompt user to enter 3 characters
    var charOne = prompt('Enter a character.');
    var charTwo = prompt('Enter another character.');
    var charThree = prompt('Enter one last character.');
    console.log(charThree);

    //prompt user for pattern size
    var size = prompt('I will generate a pattern for you. Give me a size.');

    //check
    console.log('Still going.');

    //loops until number is givin
    while (isNaN(size) === true){
        if(isNaN(size) === true){
        alert('Not a number!');
        size = prompt('Give me a number.'); 
         } else {
       } 
    } 
    console.log('Outta the loop');

    //nested for loop for pattern
   /* for(var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
       for(var y = 1; y < size; y++){
       document.write(charOne,charTwo,charThree + '<br>');
       }
    }
    */
   // console.log('Outta nested loop');

    /*
    var cols = [];
    var rows = size;
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
         cols[i] = [];
   }*/

    /*
    var iMax = size;
    var jMax = size;
    var f = [charOne,charTwo,charThree];

    for(i = 0; i < iMax; i++) {
        f[i] = [charOne,charTwo,charThree];
        for(j = 0; j < jMax; j++) {
            f[i][j] = 0;
            document.write(charOne,charTwo,charThree + '<br>');
        }
        }
     */

    //an arry to make a pattern
    chars = [charOne, charTwo, charThree];

    for(var x = 0; x < size; x++){
        for(var y = 1; y < size; y++){
            document.write(chars[x] + chars[y] + '<br>');
        }

    }


    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: can you provide the expected output for a set of inputs?

Comment: Can you sketch a basic example?

Comment: "form a pattern of some sort and generate an interesting pattern" You're trying to list out all the combinations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you trying to achieve here, (you should give us an example of the result you hope to get), but I'm already seeing on problem in your loop:

```
chars = [charOne, charTwo, charThree];

for(var x = 0; x < size; x++){
    for(var y = 1; y < size; y++){
        // Here you take the xth and yth indexes
        // of the chars Array which only has 3 entries
        // document.write(chars[x] + chars[y] + '<br>');
        // You could try this:
        document.write(chars[0] + chars[1] + '<br>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say I've entered ABC, therefore `chars = ['A', 'B', 'C']`, assuming the `size` I've entered is 5, then the access to `chars` will go as follow:

```
chars[0] = 'A'
chars[1] = 'B'
chars[2] = 'C'
chars[3] = undefined
chars[4] = undefined
```

As you can see, you have an index out of bounds error here.

If I understand you correctly, you want the print the letters on each cell in the grid? If not then please let me know, if it is then this should solve it:

```
for(var x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    for(var y = 1; y < size; y++){
        document.write(charOne + charTwo + charThree + '<br>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your loop could be iterating through array elements that are undefined.  For example if numbers a, b, c are entered and someone enters 5 as the size then you could be trying to print values for an array that has only a size of 3 [0, 1, 2] but going out to and index of [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]. Char[3] and Char[4] don't exist.  I suggest that size be the outer for loop and you use the size of the Char[] array (3) to limite the two inner loops.  In your case set inner loops to go through char.length to avoid undefined.

```
chars = [charOne, charTwo, charThree];
    for (var z = 0; z < size; z++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < chars.length; x++) {
            for (var y = 1; y < chars.length; y++) {
                document.write(chars[x] + chars[y] + '<br>');
            }
        }
    }
```